# Unable to get intended results using "OR" on specific fields in normal query. Can Solr do OR queries on specific fields?

Tags: solr

Can you make OR queries on specific fields? For example, could you do `(main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1*)) OR (main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.2*))`?

I've read the [documentation](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.5.pdf) for our version (5.5) and they use examples ***without*** specific fields, such as:

```
"jakarta apache" jakarta
```

or

```
"jakarta apache" OR jakarta
```

---

**NOTE**: I am able to get the intended results using filter-queries, but my goal is to get the same results using a normal query. The fq that works is `main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1* 1920.2*)`.

---

**EDIT1**: The regular queries I have tried, that should work, but do not work, are:

1. `(main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1*)) OR (main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.2*))`
2. `main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1* OR 1920.2*)`
3. `main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1* 1920.2*)`

Comment: Yes, that should work. `main_ref_number_tesim:(1920.1* OR 1920.2*)` should also work. What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: @MatsLindh right? I added the queries that I tried already in EDIT1, hope it helps.

Comment: Well, it also depends on the type of the field - if you have a tokenizer that splits on `.` (like the standardtokenizer does, iirc), you won't get _any_ matches when doing wildcard searches, but then it's weird that the filter query works. A filter query and a regular query are identical, but you might be using a different query parser in how `q` is being processed?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make OR for a specific fields.

```
@Query(value = "*:*", filters = "(keywords:(?0))")
public Page<ENITITY> findDataByKeywords(List<String> keywords,Pageable pageable);
```

Like in above code when you pass list of keywords OR operation will be applied by solr on keywords.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: I guess this answer is talking about spring data solr, but isn't the question is about solr in general, not spring data?

Comment: Not sure how to interpret this answer. Assuming it's "spring data solr" based on @Persimmonium's comment - ok, yeah, I googled it https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/. Is that some sort of DSL or programming language to interact with the solr API?